# the request was aborted could not create ssl/tls secure channel

Tags: c#

I'm using .net 4.0 version and it is working fine in local system, but when hosted in the server I get the error "the request was aborted could not create ssl/tls secure channel" error throwed.

How to solve it?

```
public static string GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    try
    {

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), enc);
        var result = string.Empty;
        result = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
        return result;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return "";// ex.Message;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return "";// e.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your version of .Net to 4.6 or above. I suspect the website your connecting has upgraded its web server and that has deprecated the SSL method which the .Net 4.0 client uses to connect.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a better way:
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= (SecurityProtocolType) 3840;`
Unlike in your case exclusively setting TLS 1.2, the example above simply *adds* TLS 1.1. and TLS 1.2.

Alternatively, it could also be due to wrong certificate, bade client/server time stamps and numerous other issues. Try opening it in browser. Does it work?